# Vertex Buffers - indexed or direct, interlaced or separate

Tags: opengl

What are some common guidelines in choosing vertex buffer type? When should we use interlaced buffers for vertex data, and when separate ones? When should we use an index array and when direct vertex data?

I'm searching for some common quidelines - I some cases where one or the opposite fits better, but not all cases are easily solvable. What should one have in mind choosing the vertex buffer format when aiming for performance?

Links to web resources on the topic are also welcome.

Comment: Would the downvoter share his reasons?

Comment: +1 No idea about the downvote, the question looks interesting to me, looking forwards for an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First of all, you can find some [useful information](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Specification_Best_Practices) on the OpenGL wiki. Second of all, if in doubt, profile, there are some rules-of-thumb about this one but experience can vary based on the data set, hardware, drivers, ... .

### Indexed versus direct rendering

I would almost always by default use the indexed method for vertex buffers. The main reason for this is the so called [post-transform cache](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Post_Transform_Cache). It's a cache kept after the vertex processing stage of your graphics pipeline. Essentially it means that if you use a vertex multiple times you have a good chance of hitting this cache and being able to skip the vertex computation. There is one condition to even hit this cache and that is that you need to use indexed buffers, it won't work without them as the index is a part of this cache's key.

Also, you likely will save storage, an index can be as small as you want (1 byte, 2 byte) and you can reuse a full vertex specification. Suppose that a vertex and all attributes total to about 30 bytes of data and you share this vertex over let's say 2 polygons. With indexed rendering (2 byte indices) this will cost you `2*index_size+attribute_size = 34 byte`. With non-indexed rendering this will cost you 60 bytes. Often your vertices will be shared more than twice.

Is index-based rendering always better? No, there might be scenarios where it's worse. For very simple applications it might not be worth the code overhead to set up an index-based data model. Also, when your attributes are not shared over polygons (e.g. normal per-polygon instead of per-vertex) there is likely no vertex-sharing at all and IBO's won't give a benefit, only overhead.

Next to that, while it enables the post-transform cache, it does make generic memory cache performance worse. Because you access the attributes relatively random, you might have quite some more cache misses and memory prefetching (if this would be done on the GPU) won't work decently. So it might be (but measure) that if you have enough memory and your vertex shader is extremely simple that the non-indexed version outperforms the indexed version.

### Interleaving vs non-interleaving vs buffer per-attribute

This story is a bit more subtle and I think it comes down to weighing some properties of your attributes.

1. Interleaved might be better because all attributes will be close together and likely be in a few memory cachelines (maybe even a single one). Obviously, this can mean better peformance. However, combined with indexed-based rendering your memory access is quite random anyway and the benefit might be smaller than you'd expect.
2. Know which attributes are static and which are dynamic. If you have 5 attributes of which 2 are completely static, 1 changes every 15 minutes and 2 every 10 seconds, consider putting them in 2 or 3 separate buffers. You don't want to re-upload all 5 attributes every time those 2 most frequent change.
3. Consider that attributes should be aligned on 4 bytes. So you might want to take interleaving even one step further from time to time. Suppose you have a vec3 1-byte attribute and some scalar 1-byte attribute, naively this will need 8 bytes. You might gain a lot by putting them together in a single vec4, which should reduce usage to 4 bytes.
4. Play with buffer size, a too large buffer or too many small buffers may impact performance. But this is likely very dependent on the hardware, driver and OpenGL implementation.

Comment: I'm not really convinced that interleaving attributes improves the cache hit rate. Vertices are most likely processed in batches. Since local memory is a scarce resource not all attributes might be loaded up front. Instead it might as well be that each attribute is loaded separately (but for all threads together) as needed. So interleaving would not reduce the number of cache lines. Making sure that your vertex indices are close together would be important.

Comment: @ThomasD: well, it depends if and how your memory is actually cached on a low level (I meant L1/L2/L3 like). such caching is relatively new on GPUs afaik. If there is no caching obviously most caching comments do not matter. If there is only TLB caching, you're right also. If there are however real L1/L2/L3 caches everything comes back to how the cachelines are managed and these generally don't know about the attributes separately, only of chunks of memory.

Comment: Then, if you indeed consider caching as copying to shared memory (not global). I doubt this will ever happen, I'd assume shared memory is used mainly to store uniforms (or of course shared variables in compute shaders). But of course, theoretically an implementation can use this as a cache, but then it comes down to the same thing: try and measure.

Comment: The problem with profiling is that as an indie I can only profile on my own machine. I hate it when people answer "do profiling on different cards", that may be viable for big studios, but not for independent developers. I hope sticking to these reasonably sounding guidelines will suffice... Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz That's not necessarily true, even for an indie dev. If you think about it, there's a lot of places to test; your friends' machines, community (if you're open source or distributing binaries already)... Even the big studios can't possibly test every configuration possible, but then again, it doesn't need to be *perfect*. You only need *good enough*, and that's somehow comforting :)

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz Profiling can be useful even on one GPU. As I stated several times, the properties of your data set itself can also be important. From time to time the best storage method itself is not clear and you need profiling, even if it's on a limited set of GPU's

Comment: On my own machine I profile thoroughly, but it's a monster compared to the minimum specs I target. A closed beta will probably help, as long as I prepare the proper outputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Indexed vs Direct

Let's see what you get by indexing. Every repeating vertex, that is, a vertex with "smooth" break will cost you less. Every singular "edge" vertex will cost you more. For data that's based on real world and is relatively dense, one vertex will belong to many triangles, and thus indexes will speed it up. For procedurally generated arbitrary data, direct mode will usually be better.

Indexed buffers also add additional complications to the code.

### Interleaved vs Separate

The main difference here is actually based on a question "*will I want to update only one component?*". If the answer is *yes*, then you shouldn't interleave, because any update will be extremely costly. If it's *no*, using interleaved buffers should improve locality of reference and generally be faster on most of the hardware.

Comment: That being said, I usually use separate, indexed buffers. They feel the most intuitive, and some GL inspection tools (like gDebugger) work best on simple buffers (not-interleaved).

Comment: +1'd before. By procedurally generated arbitrary data you mean stuff like particle systems only? Because for procedural terrain you'd be wasting a lot space without indexes... or am I wrong?

Comment: @Kornel Oh, that very much depends. For example, in my Minecraft clone I needed the updates to the displayed structure (the "outer shell" of the cubes). Thus, I am reconstructing the chunk VBO everytime the user removes or adds a cube. The gain on the indexing wasn't much there (the texture changes from cube to cube and you can't reuse vertices easily), and the process of constructing indices dynamically was taking longer, so it was simpler to just make a big blob of data and push it through, thus offloading the CPU (GPUs are absurdly fast at rendering plain data anyway).

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz However for a regular tiled heightmap you'd save theoretically 3/4 of the vertex memory, and since heightmaps aren't usually "broken", the indexed approach would most certainly improve it. I think the choice must be made with the full knowledge about the problem being solved, and simple "rules of thumb" don't always cut it. Therefore I always start with something that's easier and more intuitive to implement, and fine-tune later.